# Why does this code works/fails depending on scope closure is created at?

Tags: c++, templates, closures

The following code wraps a callback in another callback, but depending on the scope the inner callback was made, the code either runes successfully or fails spectacularly.

The code below, as is, runs fine, but if the callback is done inside `make_callback()` instead of directly in `main` the code fails:

```
frame #110339: 0x000000010000453c a.out`std::__1::__function::__func<void stuff<B>(std::__1::function<void (B*)>)::'lambda'(A*), std::__1::allocator<void stuff<B>(std::__1::function<void (B*)>)::'lambda'(A*)>, void (A*)>::operator()(A*&&) + 60

frame #110340: 0x0000000100002fdf a.out`std::__1::function<void (A*)>::operator()(A*) const + 159
```

code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <list>

class A {
public:
  virtual ~A(){}
};

class B : public A {
public:
  virtual ~B(){}
};


std::list<std::function<void(A*)>> callbacks;
void stuff(std::function<void(A*)> callback){
  callbacks.push_back(callback);
  printf("Now have %d callbacks\n", (int)callbacks.size());

}

template<typename T>
void stuff(std::function<void(T*)> callback) {


  stuff([&](A* a) {
      T * b = dynamic_cast<T*>(a);
      if (b!= nullptr) {
        printf("Calling actual callback\n");
        callback(b);
      } else {
        printf("Not calling actual callback\n");
      }
    }
    );
}

void make_callback()
{
  stuff<B>([&](B*b){printf("Hello with a B\n");});
}

int main()
{
  //make_callback();                                                                                                 
  stuff<B>([&](B*b){printf("Hello with a B\n");});

  A a;
  B b;
  for (auto callback : callbacks) {
    callback(&a);
    callback(&b);
  }
}
```

Comment: You capture the function parameter by reference, and it dangles once the call to `stuff<B>` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to your reference-capture inside the `stuff` template, `callback` is a dangling reference when the function gets called. (It refers to the parameter, and the parameter's lifetime has ended.)
As always, using a dangling reference is undefined and may or may not appear to work.

There is no need for reference capture in this code.